# How to represent it in a Fourier transform way?

Tags: fourier-transform

Given $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}~u(x,t)~x^2~e^{-ikx}~dx$$

How to represent it in a Fourier transform way?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}[u(x,t)x^2]$?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, this is by definition the Fourier transform of $u(x,t)x^2$. Note that $u(x,t)x^2$ has to be in a space for which the Fourier transform is defined, so e.g. $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Did you mean the second derivative of the Fourier transform fo $u$?

Comment: I mean, this is a form of Fourier transform for the product of two functions, u(x,t) and x^2

Comment: I am not sure how to write it in a way of u hat